# Can I download historical data with the OSMnx package in Python?

Tags: python, openstreetmap, osmnx

Let's say, download the highway network for a given city the way it was present in OSM on December 3, 2018.

If not OSMnx, what are other ways to download historical data? The Overpass API gave me an overload error for certain places.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use OSMnx to retrieve OSM data, such as a street network, as of a certain date. This gives you a historical snapshot of what was present in OpenStreetMap as of a certain date and time. You can configure OSMnx's `overpass_settings` setting to do this, as explained in the [documentation](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/osmnx.html#module-osmnx.settings):

> To query, for example, historical OSM data as of a certain date: ‘[out:json][timeout:90][date:”2019-10-28T19:20:00Z”]’. Use with caution.